# Scaling Animation iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone describe a way to create an animated scaling affect on the iPhone?  I would like an image to start small, and then grow while fading. Motion tweening would also be helpful. Is quartz neccessary for this? I'd prefer to use something as simple as possible.

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
myImageView.size = CGSizeMake(myImageView.size.width*2,myImageView.size.height*2);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This does require the CoreAnimations framework to be added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all using UIViews/CALayer.

If the values you wish to expand to are predefined it's very easy.

you can use a CABasicAnimation where you set the new CGSize for the view/layer, and the length of the transition, coupled with another where you adjust the opacity of the view/layer. Add these two animations to the view. Motion tweening can be achieved by adjusting the position/frame of the object inside of a animation block.

This [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW1) from the apple documentation on Core Animation for more information, and some basic examples